# Archiving mutable array - doesNotRecognizeSelector exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, immutability, archiving

I'm having an "doesNotRecognizeSelector" exception and I suspect that maybe my unarchiver return immutable array intstead of mutable.
Am I right ? how should I do the archiving and archiving properly ? (place of exception is show down)

Thanks!!!

```
NSMutableArray* arr;

- (void) write
{
         NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
         NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];

 NSMutableArray *copy = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.Arr] copy];
        [archiver encodeObject:copy forKey:@"Key"];
        [archiver finishEncoding];
        [data writeToFile:[Util DataPath] atomically:YES];
        [archiver release];
        [data release];
        [copyOfPaidPacks release];
}




-(NSMutableArray*) read
{
    NSString* DataPath = [Util FilePath];
    NSData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = nil;
    if (data != nil)
    {
            unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc]initForReadingWithData:data];

    if([self.Arr count] <= 0)
    {
        self.Arr = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"Key"];  
    }
}

[unarchiver finishDecoding];
[unarchiver release];
[data release];
    return self.arr
}

-(void)B
{
     [self write];
     NSMutableArray* SecondArr = [self read];
     [SecondArr sortUsingSelector:@selector(CompareDate:)]; - > `****THIS IS WHERE I GET THE EXCEPTION`
}
```

- Edit

Adding the compare method:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)CompareDate:(T*)p
{
    NSComparisonResult result = [self.changeDate compare:p.changeDate];
    if(result == NSOrderedDescending)
        result = NSOrderedAscending;
    else if(result == NSOrderedAscending)
        result = NSOrderedDescending;

    if(result == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        result = [self CompareName:p];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is the selector it doesn't recognize? EDIT: Okay, scrolled down and see now. Have you defined a custom `CompareDate:` method? Also, what kind of objects are in your array?

Comment: I did defind it. I added code so you review it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSKeyedUnarchiver` does indeed return an immutable `NSArray`. If you really want to get an `NSMutableArray`, you'd need to call `-mutableCopy` on the return value from `decodeObjectForKey:`.

This code snippet makes me wonder if you really even need a mutable array though. It looks like you're just sorting the array you get from `-read`. Why not just call `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` on the immutable NSArray instead?

Comment: I assumed it has to be mutable to be sorted , cause sorting by definition changes position of objects in the array. (meaning adding and removing). Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Idan: You cannot perform an *in-place* sort on an immutable array, but you can ask any array for a version of itself sorted by a particular selector (or function), with `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` mentioned by kperryua.

Comment: Ok I get it, so how do you explain the unrecognized selector exception ? the weird thing is that most of the time it works. any idea ?

Comment: NSArray simply doesn't respond to -sortUsingSelector: since it's a mutation method, so Objective-C threw the exception. I'm not sure why this would "most of the time".

Answer (score 3):

You already pass an immutable array to the archiver, so why would you expect the unarchiver to return a mutable one then?

If you want a copy to be mutable, then you have to use

```
NSMutableArray *copy = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.Arr] mutableCopy];
```

as

```
NSMutableArray *copy = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.Arr] copy];
```

will create an immutable copy (at least as far, as you should be concerned. In reality the framework will often use a mutable internal representation for immutable instances, but this is an implementation detail and you should not count on it, as these representations have changed in the past and the Cocoa docs explicitly tell you, to not check for the internal representation).

EDIT:
just tested with NSKeyedArchiver myself on iOS 5.0 simulator:

```
// this returns a mutable instance at runtime!
NSMutableArray* test0 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[NSMutableArray array]]];
// this returns an immutable instance at runtime!
NSArray* test1 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[NSArray array]]];
```

So your problem is really exclusively caused by using copy instead of mutableCopy, while archiving and unarchiving keeps the correct mutability-attributes of the instances!

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where archiving a 3-dimensional mutable array (ie, a mutable array of mutable arrays of mutable arrays) would unarchive as a mutable array of immutable arrays of immutable arrays.

The key to fixing this was to subclass NSKeyedUnarchiver and overwrite

```
- (Class)classForClassName:(NSString *)codedName
{
    Class theClass = [super classForClassName: codeName];

    if ([codeName isEqualToString: NSStringFromClass(NSArray.class))
    {
        theClass = NSMutableArray.class;
    }
    //... more here like NSDictionary
    return theClass;
}
```